# Minimum # of Compound Indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Consider Mongo's example of [Compound Indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound):

```
Example Given the following index:
{ "item": 1, "location": 1, "stock": 1 }
MongoDB can use this index to support queries that include:   

 - the item field, and
 - the item field and the location field, and
 - the item field and the location field and the stock field.

MongoDB cannot use this index to support queries that include:


 - only the location field,
 - only the stock field,
 - only the location and stock fields, and
 - only the item and stock fields.
```

Is there a better **minimum** # of indexes required to be able to support any "exact-match" query combination of item, location and stock than simply the *permutation*?

**EDIT**

To address the missing indexes above, I could add `Location`, `Stock`, `Location-Stock`, and `Item-Stock` indexes. Note the last 2 are compound-indexes to handle all queries listed in my question.

But, is there a general rule when trying to handle all permutations for N fields?

Comment: Can't you work this out? It seems simple enough more that your just trying to get us to do your math for you

Comment: edited per your appropriate chide, Sammaye. Thank you for it.

Comment: Don't store the data that way -- you'd need to store it more "key/value/type" to possibly reduce the number of permutations of indexes that could be required.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, please explain further. I don't follow.

Comment: Me neither. :)  I mixed in another database's capabilities in my head as part of the solution I was thinking about, making an evil/impossible mix. So, never-mind.

Comment: so I'd only need to add a `Location`, `Stock`, `Location-Stock`, and `Item-Stock` indexes. Note the last 2 are compound-indexes to handle all queries listed in my question. Is there a general rule when trying to handle all permutations for `N` fields?

Answer (score 0):

> I could add `Location`, `Stock`, `Location-Stock`, and `Item-Stock` indexes. Note the last 2 are compound-indexes to handle all queries listed in my question.

If you have `Location-Stock`, you won't need a separate `Location` index.

You might want to watch [MongoDB's Jira for updates on index intersection](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071). Index intersection will solve this problem. The [new matcher](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/51574091391/mongodbs-new-matcher) is already in place in the 2.5 branch.

In general, throwing in (almost) all permutations is unfeasible since the number of permutations is `N!`, so that's 24 indexes for 4 fields and 120 indexes for 5 fields.

Make sure your index *selectivity* is good. This depends heavily on the data (i.e. how the relations are distributed) and the application (the queries you need), which makes the discussion tricky.

For instance, let's say a typical customer has 5,000 items in stock, but nobody has more than 5 locations. In that case, the `location` index might not be too helpful. The worst case is a query for all items in a specific location. The DB would have to look at 25k documents to return 5k results.

That's not too efficient, but it's unlikely that the user wants to query the entire list very often. For a typical application where you just want to show the first page, the effectiveness of this query will depend on the insertion order and the type of you primary key: If the documents have a random key, the db will have to scan `5n` documents to return `n` results on average. If, however, the primary key is monotonic and the data was inserted location-by-location, the db might have to scan and skip 20k elements just to find the first result!

So, the long answer is: indexes are a tool that must be carefully adjusted to the data and the queries you need, so there's no generally applicable minimum bound that is helpful for practical purposes.